# Spring Data JPA: issues with cascading ManyToMany relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many, cascade

I have a ManyToMany relationship between `Role` and `Scope`. I made it bidirectional in order to be able to use `CascadeType.REMOVE` on Role.

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "scope_name", columnNames = "name"))
public class Scope {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @JoinTable(name = "role_scopes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scope_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Role> roles;

}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "role_name", columnNames = "name"))
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Scope> scopes;

}
```

The intention is to:

1. When a `Scope` is deleted, it's deletion must be cascaded into all the tables on which there is a relationship with Scope, eg: `scopeRepository.deleteById(someId)` should also delete records from the `role_scopes` table. **(working)**
2. `Scope` must be persisted either by `scopeRepository.save(scope)` and through `Role`, if this Role is not yet related with this Scope, eg: `roleRepository.save(role.withScopes(scope1, scope2).build())`. If `scope1` does not exist, create a `scope` and also a `role_scopes` value. If `scope2` does exist but does not have any relation with the role, crete a `role_scopes` value only. **(not working)**

Brand new `Scope` can be created through `Role` using the `CascadeType.PERSIST`, but if that scope already exists, it throws a `detached entity passed to persist` error but I would like Hibernate to simply ignore the Scope creation (in this case) and check whether there's also a `role_scopes` record and create one if there isn't, otherwise simply ignore that too (dont even update values).

Consider the following snippet:

```
Scope scope1 = new Scope("foo");
Scope scope2 = new Scope("bar");
Role role1 = Role.builder("foobar").withScopes(scope1, scope2).build();

roleRepository.save(role1);
```

Scenario 1) `scope`, `role` and `role_scopes` tables are empty:

```
should create role1, scope1 and scope2 and their relationships (role1 vs scope1 and role1 vs scope2) on role_scopes table
```

Scenario 2) `role` table is empty, `scope1` and `scope2` exist but aren't related to any role (empty `role_scopes` table):

```
should create role1 and it's relationships (role1 vs scope1 and role1 vs scope2) on role_scopes table
```

Scenario 3) `role` table is empty, `scope1` exists and is related to `role1` (`role_scopes` not empty) and `scope2` does not exist:

```
should create role1, scope2 and their relationship (role1 vs scope2) on role_scopes table
```

Scenario 4) `role1`, `scope1` and `scope2` exist and are both related to `role1`:

```
do nothing
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get JPA to do so much? You should start with a minimal JPA configuration and write a service layer to do this sort of work. If convenient and useful optimizations are obvious after that then use them, otherwise let the service layer do what it is made for.

Comment: Why is this too much? This is a framework after all. Spring does have many things implemented, mainly the Boot module, so why not?

Comment: You should start with a minimal JPA configuration and write a service layer to do this sort of work. If convenient and useful optimizations are obvious after that then use them, otherwise let the service layer do what it is made for.